# One one onto mapping

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to understand equivalent set as we know two set is said to be equivalent if there exist one one onto mapping, but I don't understand what is one one onto mapping? Please help me how Natural to even natural number have 1—1 onto mapping.

Comment: You need to first understand what is an '1-1' mapping and what is an 'onto' mapping. Then we are dealing here with mappings that are *both* '1-1' and 'onto'.

Answer (score 2):

For every natural number $n$ exist even number $2n$ and for every even positive number $2k$ exist natural number $k$.

Another example.

$\mathbb{Z}\sim \mathbb{N}$. For every not negative integer number $n$ exist natural number $2n+1$ and for negative integer number $n$ exist natural number $-2n$.